# Foreach loop on XPathNodeIterator not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, xquery

I am trying to foreach on an XPathNodeIterator object

```
    XPathNodeIterator xpCategories = GetCategories();
```

now xpCategories holds an xml like this

```
 <root>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>format</id>
    <name>Kopi/Print</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="1">
    <id>frankering</id>
    <name>Kopi/Print</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardbøjler</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardknager</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardspejle</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>

</root>
```

And I need to get each of the category nodes "id" inside the loop.tried some thing like this

```
foreach (char str in xpCategories.Current.Value)
    {
        xpCategories.MoveNext();
    }
```

But of no use..Can any one guide me to the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  //Replace with your method to return the XML
  XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("DemoXML.xml"); 
  //*****

  XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

  XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/root/category/id");

  while (nodes.MoveNext())
      Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.Value);
```

Edit:

```
XPathNodeIterator xpCategories = GetCategories();
XPathNodeIterator xpCategoriesID = xpCategories.Current.Select("root/category/id");

while (xpCategoriesID.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(xpCategoriesID.Current.Value);
```

Comment: I am un able to use this code as I am getting data in XPathNodeIterator form from third party dll..Ican't create new XML document as you said

Comment: Ok, try the sample above?

Answer (score 1):

```
XPathNodeIterator xpCategories = GetCategories().Current.Select("/root/category/id");    
while (xpCategories.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(xpCategories.Current.Value);
```